# Symfony request: get empty array from a empty multivalued parameter send by POST?

Tags: symfony, post, request

Cient send a POST request with this parameter:

```
data[]
```

data[] has no value.
(in another situation, multiple data[] send ids from a multiselection combobox and its fine. But problem occurs when there is no selection in the combobox)

In Symfony v3.4 I get data like this:

```
$data = $request->get('data')

var_dump($data); // array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

I expect to get an empty array, not an array filed with one value.

Is there a way to get an empty array **straight from $request**, reflecting the parameter send to server ?
Or may this be a "by design" POST consequence ?
Or client have to send no data[] parameter when there is no selection in combobox ?

Note, i already got this "solution", which i'd like to avoid:

```
if ((count($data) == 0) && ($data[0] == ''))
    $data = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get post data:

```
$data = $request->request->get('data');
```

Comment: Same result, an array filed with a zero length string.